# Ubuntu-Phone - SIP/VOIP

Tags: ubuntu-touch, encryption, voip, sip

On some dev notes I read about that this was beeing tested. How far are we on this and will it be added. A native SIP client would be very interesting as Ubuntu-Phone would be the only open OS, Android & iOS & WP and so on are not.

I do understand that App developers can make this, old android (4.4 if i remember correctly) had native sip support, apps are just not it.

Currently I bought a Aquarius 4.5 for this as testing, due that that techies are great, but general information about Ubuntu OS are EXTREMELY limited for non-geeks.

Comment: I have strong interest in this and would be willing to donate for any project bringing SIP to Ubuntu Touch/Nexus 4. How about linphone? There is a web version, which is going to be discontinued due to compability issues with Chrome/Firefox. Looking forward to your reactions! [Tanzbaer](http://askubuntu.com/users/548018/tanzbaer)